# Is it safe to delete "Account Unknown" entries from Windows ACLs in a domain environment?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions

It's not uncommon to see entries in Windows ACLs (NTFS files/folders, registry, AD objects, etc.) with the name "Account Unknown (SID)". Obviously these are because of old AD users or groups which at some point had permissions manually configured on the relevant object and have since been deleted.

Does anyone know if it is safe to remove these "Account Unknown" ACEs?

My gut feeling is that it should be just fine, but I'm wondering if anyone has any past experiences where doing this has caused trouble?

Normally I just ignore these, but the company I'm working at now seems to have an abnormal number of these, most likely due to past admins' inexperience with AD/Windows and assigning permissions to user accounts rather than groups in all sorts of weird places.

FWIW, our environment is not complex, a single domain forest, 4 DCs in 3 sites, with all network connectivity and replication healthy, so I'm certain that these "Account Unknown" entries are really old accounts, and not just because of some failure to resolve the SID to a human-readable name.

Comment: You shouldn't really have ACL entries for individual users in the first place, you should be setting them at group level in order to avoid this sort of problem and to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: I know that, but this cruft is a result of several people having a hand in AD administration in the past and none of them having any real concept of generally accepted best practices.

Comment: There are so many things that would be different in an ideal world. Unfortunately, we don't live in that world. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you have no connectivity problems, yes, it's safe to delete them. Do be careful because Windows will show "Account Unknown" if it can't connect to AD, or if you have multiple domains it might take a few moments to cross the domain boundaries, etc.

Comment: As per the original question: *"single domain forest, 4 DCs in 3 sites, with all network connectivity and replication healthy, so I'm certain that these "Account Unknown" entries are really old accounts"*

Comment: I know, but I wanted to throw that part in there as others in different situations will inevitably read this answer, without having ready anything more than the title of your question.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it more.  Explaining the "why" behind your answer is really important on serverfault where any "basic" information questions tend to get moved to superuser

Answer (score 1):

take a backup and go ahead.

Assuming you don't have any trusts with other domains, and as earlier pointed out, any network connectivity issues.

you can take backup of ACLs using xcacls.exe or icacls.exe (Vista and above)
They can be in format such a way that, you can copy paste and reapply them back.